# I have nested list, task to find maximum cost, but if two cost are the same then keep only one which weight is lower, and also find 2nd highest cost

Tags: python

```
ls = [[2, 33.8, 40], [3, 43.15, 10], [4, 37.97, 16], [5, 46.81, 36], [6, 48.77, 79], [8, 19.36, 79], [9, 6.76, 64]]

fn = [ls[0]]

for v in ls:
    if v not in fn:            
        if v[2] == fn[0][2]:
            if (v[2]+v[1]) < (fn[0][1]+fn[0][2]) and len(fn) <=1:
                fn.append(v)
            else:
                fn.append(v)
        if v[2] != fn[0][2] and v[2] > fn[0][2]:
            fn.pop(0)
            fn.append(v)
print(fn)
```

But it gives out like this = [[6, 48.77, 79], [8, 19.36, 79]]
i want out first keeps only lowest weight where 2 cost are similar and find 2 highest and append to fn. Expected out put [[8, 19.36, 79],[9, 6.76, 64]]

In given list where first index(0) --> represents index, index(1) --> weight, index(2) --> cost

For and example [[2, 33.8, 40]] 2--> index, 33.8 --> weight, 40--> cost

Comment: given `[6, 48.77, 79]`, 79 is cost and 48.77 is weight?

Comment: your code doesn't say what each variable is so how can we guess what is cost and what is weight? if you are struggling with debugging this code, try giving variables readable names and reading the logic to yourself and you will probably find your mistake.

Comment: yes 6 --> index, 48.77 --> weight and 79 --> cost

Comment: try using `for index, weight, cost in ls:` and using these variables instead of v. your code will make more sense then and you will have less trouble debugging it

Answer (score 0):

This should help:-

```
ls = [[2, 33.8, 40],
    [3, 43.15, 10],
    [4, 37.97, 16],
    [5, 46.81, 36],
    [6, 48.77, 79],
    [8, 19.36, 79],
    [9, 6.76, 64]]


def process(mls):
    sl = sorted(mls, reverse=True, key=lambda x: (x[2], x[1]))
    r = [sl[0], None]
    while len(sl) > 2 and sl[0][2] == sl[1][2]:
        r[0], r[1] = sl[1], sl[2]
        sl.pop(0)
    return [x for x in r if x is not None]


print(process(ls))
```

Comment: Thank you so much immediately reply, this works great if 2 cost is similar but what if in next of file ls = [[1, 53.38, 45], [3, 78.48, 3], [4, 72.3, 76], [5, 30.18, 9], [6, 46.34, 48]], here cost is unique no repeatetion hence out put must be --> [4, 72.3, 76] because it is highest cost